# Find a way to dampen a linear function

Tags: functions

This question is related to statistics, but those guys do everything recursively and I'm certain there must be a more mathematical solution to my problem.

I'm looking for a way to dampen a linear function so that it approaches a limit, ideally a real number but even infinity very slowly as would a logarithmic function is fine.

So say I have a function like $f(x) = 1 + 0.5x$. Then I want a function that decreases the slope with growing $x$.

I've spent hours reading and thinking about this and cannot even come up with a function that behaves the way I want (apart from a log function). Let alone to find a way to convert my linear function to behave like this.

Let me know if any more information is necessary.

If it is in any way helpful, in statistics the slope would be called a trend and would be dampened recursively by a dampening factor $G_{t+1}= α + (1 - α)*G_t$ with $0 <= α <= 1$.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my own question, in case anyone ever needs this.

I just randomly stumbled upon what I was looking for back then. A function that behaves the way I wanted is:

$$f(x) = a + b*x + c*\sqrt{x}$$